# Can't recuperate content of commit on tag creation

Tags: java, git, groovy, bitbucket, hook

I am working on a pre-receive hook using Scriptrunner for Bitbucket Server that checks the content of a repository whenever you create a Tag on Bitbucket. The script checks if there is a file named "conanfile.py" if there is none, the tag is created and if there is one, it checks the inside of the file, compare the inside with a regex and if there is some lines not matching the regex, block the tag creation. Here is the code :

```java
    log.warn('Starting pre-receive hook')
    if (refChanges.any { it.ref.id.startsWith("refs/tags/") && it.type == RefChangeType.ADD && it.fromHash == "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}) {

    log.warn('Ref change detected')

    @ShortTextInput(label = 'regex', description = 'Regex expression used to verify file content')
    String regexValue
    def pattern = Pattern.compile(".*requires\\(\"[^\\d_\\-](\\S)+/(\\[\\d{1,3}(\\.\\d{1,3})*\\]|\\d(\\.\\d)*)@(eca|exail)")
    def commitService = ComponentLocator.getComponent(CommitService)
    def contentService = ComponentLocator.getComponent(ContentService)
    def commits = refChanges.getCommits(repository) as List<Commit>

    log.warn("Number of commits: ${commits.size()}")

    def filePaths = [:] as Map<String, String>
    commits.reverseEach { commit ->
        def changesRequest = new ChangesRequest.Builder(repository, commit.id).build()
        commitService.streamChanges(changesRequest) { Change change ->
            if (change.path.toString().endsWith("conanfile.py")) {
                filePaths[change.path.toString()] = commit.id
            }
            true
        }
    }

    log.warn("Number of files: ${filePaths.size()}")

    def result = true
    def lineCount = 0
    def matchCount = 0

    filePaths.keySet().each { filePath ->
        def fileStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        contentService.streamFile(repository, filePaths[filePath], filePath) {
            fileStream
        }
        fileStream.toString().split("\n").each { line ->
            if (line.startsWith("        self.requires")) {
                lineCount++
                log.warn("Line count: ${lineCount}")
                def match = pattern.matcher(line)
                if (match.find()) {
                    matchCount++
                    log.warn("Match count: ${matchCount}")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (lineCount != matchCount) {
        result = false
    } else {
        result = true
    }

    if (result) {
        log.warn('Pre-receive hook succeeded')
        return RepositoryHookResult.accepted()
    } else {
        log.warn('Pre-receive hook failed')
        return RepositoryHookResult.rejected('Tag non crée ', 'Vous devez figer vos versions de dependance que vous utilisez quand vous créez un tag')
    }

} else {
    log.warn('No relevant ref change detected')
    return RepositoryHookResult.accepted()
}
```

My problem is , I can't seem to make the hook understand the commit and it's always empty making the checking not working :

2023-02-22 13:19:29,551 WARN [c.o.s.r.ScriptBindingsManager]: Starting pre-receive hook

2023-02-22 13:19:29,559 WARN [c.o.s.r.ScriptBindingsManager]: Ref change detected

2023-02-22 13:19:29,608 WARN [c.o.s.r.ScriptBindingsManager]: Number of commits: 0

2023-02-22 13:19:29,609 WARN [c.o.s.r.ScriptBindingsManager]: Number of files: 0

2023-02-22 13:19:29,610 WARN [c.o.s.r.ScriptBindingsManager]: Pre-receive hook succeeded

What is wrong with this code ?